# Why/How is IntelliJ causing debug output in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea

Yesterday I was debugging a Java application with Netbeans. (i.e. the application was running with the debugger attached) At the same time I was working with IntelliJ on a Rails application.

I noticed two strange messages in the Netbeans debug output window:

```
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingTransferableData$FoldingData"
while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref;
class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingTransferableData$FoldingData
```

and

```
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.ReferenceTransferableData$ReferenceData"
while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref;
class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.ReferenceTransferableData$ReferenceData
```

Just out of curiosity: **What was happening here?**

If it matters: I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 and IntelliJ 10.5.2 (Evaluation) with the Ruby plugin.

Comment: Oracle bug report for this is [JDK-6606476: Uncatchable exception printed to console for certain clipboard contents](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6606476).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not IDEA causing any output but Netbeans. Netbeans is trying to analyze the contents of the clipboard which contains a serialized Java object that has been put there by IDEA. Since Netbeans does not know about any IntelliJ IDEA classes, it prints this error.

Comment: me too, IDEA also analyzes the clipboard

Comment: what is even more weird in my case is that I don't use the clipboard... And the thing happens when a variable named "clipboard" comes into play, even though it has nothing to do with the systems clipboard.

Comment: Also happens in MATLAB with PyCharm. I ran `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "echo off | clip"` to clear the clipboard and restarted, and problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

This is a serialized object put in the clipboard by IntelliJ (Transferable is for clipboard operations) that is unknown to Netbeans. Nothing to worry about.