# java.lang.​ClassNotFo​undExcepti​on in matlabR2014a

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB R2014a. but sometimes give me following error:

> Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData

why? Of course I use pycharm IDE along with MATLAB. Is it because it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See this answer:
[Why/How is IntelliJ causing debug output in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846657/why-how-is-intellij-causing-debug-output-in-netbeans)

This is not related to any setup you've done within MATLAB -- it's apparently something that IntelliJ, WebStorm, or PyCharm has put into the clipboard. It goes away if you don't have one of those programs running at the same time.

Comment: indeed. i had this issue while running WEKA flow. 
I had PyCharm open, but the issue disappeared once i closed PyCharm!!

Answer (score 5):

This error indicates that MATLAB is not able to locate or read your MATLAB preferences directory. This could be due to a setting or variable on your system which is causing MATLAB to look for your preferences in a location where you do not have read access.

Typically this happens due to running a configuration script for MATLAB such as 'config_matlab.sh' which attempts to set your preferences directory to a non-default location where you do not have read or write access. You should start by removing the portion of the script which sets your environment variable.

You should choose a directory where you have both read and write access. The default location is in your home folder.

Comment: thanks. I use windows 7 platform and matlab software is in C drive that has read and write access. about a sentence that you said "You should start by removing the portion of the script which sets your environment variable." What did you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I had to copy something to the clipboard that was not from IntelliJ to get this to stop occurring. It was occurring even after I'd closed IntelliJ, presumably because of whatever remained in the Clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused when you copy something from intellij which stores serialized objects on the clipboard.

I found a workaround for this, you can just set the error stream to a different `PrintStream` than the console's err stream.
See this code

```
PrintStream errStream = System.err;
System.setErr(new PrintStream("error.log"));
```

and use the `errStream` later on to set it back. 
It is just a work around if you don't want that error to be printed on the console.