# Java intellij clipboard backup

Tags: java, intellij-idea, clipboard, classnotfoundexception

I am writing a program operating on clipboard, and I want to make backup of clipboard contents at startup, and restore it when finished. So it looks like:

```
data = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.getSystemClipboard.getContents(this);
doSomething();
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.getSystemClipboard.setContents(data, this);
```

it works fine in general, but when I copy a part of code from Intellij, and run my program, it throws:

> Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData
>
> Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData
>
> Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/jetbrains/plugins/scala/conversion/copy/Associations"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-serialized-object; class=org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.conversion.copy.Associations
>
> Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/jetbrains/plugins/scala/conversion/copy/Associations"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-serialized-object; class=org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.conversion.copy.Associations

even if doSomething function is empty.

Is it possible to backup ANY content from clipboard? If not, how to handle such problem?

Comment: in my case, if copy code in intellij and run `getSystemClipboard` would get this error, try copy plain text from notepad works.

Answer (score 2):

> "Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing
>   DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref;
>   class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData Exception
>   "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing
>   DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref;
>   class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData"

I had this error - I go to my IntelliJ to

`File -> Project Structure`

and I switched the module specific SDK from "1.8 java version...." to "IntelliJ IDEA IU -162.1447..."  and it's work fine.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: I can not found SDK you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused when you copy something from intellij which stores serialized objects on the clipboard.
I found a workaround for this. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437773/7535471)