# Eclipse - Clipboard exception "ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, intellij-idea, awt

I am developing an application in Eclipse, with frames. In some of the panels I allow the user to paste data from his clipboard. It is usually quiet. The problem is when what is on the clipboard has been copied from intelliJ (due to IntelliJ causing everything that is copied to become a serialized object) and results in an exception (`ClassNotFoundException`) and I can't catch it.

Does anyone know how to avoid this, in code?

Exception:

```
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"
    while constructing DataFlavor for: 
    application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref;
    class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java intellij clipboard backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769139/java-intellij-clipboard-backup)

Comment: @Thirumal Before asking here I spent a long time trying to solve and I also found this post. In fact it solved, but it is not only Intellij, but all JetBrains products. And if jetbrains does that, it is not impossible for other applications to do the same, which is why I wanted to find a way to prevent this from even happening :/

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer *would be* to catch the exception and ignore it.

If you can't do that, some possibilities are:

1. Develop a patch to Eclipse that allows a plugin to suppress these exceptions ... somehow<sup>1</sup>.  Then submit an Eclipse bug report, providing your patch as a solution.
2. Get the user to add the Intellij "idea.jar" file to the Eclipse classpath so that Eclipse can deserialize these objects.  You may then need to make further modifications to your plugin to allow it to make sense of the IDEA objects that you user is trying to copy and paste into Eclipse.
3. Document that your plugin does not support copy / paste from Intellij IDEA.

---

I couldn't see any way to stop Intellij from putting serialized objects into the clipboard.

---

**UPDATE** - I did some more research on this.  The string

```
"while constructing DataFlavor for:"
```

appears in the source code for `java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap`.  That suggests that the problem is actually the same one as has been reported as Java bugs [JDK-6606476](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6606476) and [8246248](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8246248).  (In the latter case, the problem is triggered by certain kinds of JPEG files.)

Examining the source code suggests that it ought to be possible to work around this problem; e.g. by creating and registering a custom `DataFlavor` and implementing a `DataContentHandler` / `DataContentHandlerFactory` to take care of the conversion<sup>2</sup>.  However, I can't give you specifics.

---

<sup>1 - It turns out that the problem is probably NOT in the Eclipse code base after all.</sup>

<sup>2 - Unless you fancy decoding Java serialization format by hand, I suggest you "deserialize" this stuff as content-free objects ... and get your application to quietly ignore DnD events for this kind of data.</sup>

Comment: The stacktrace is literally just that Exception line. The same happens if I copy something inside Intellij and paste it into a Swing made in Intellij.

I would prefer the error to be resolved only from "my side", and not require the user to do something.

Comment: The error does not stop the program, it just stops it for a few seconds, and I can, in fact (after the temporary stop) paste exactly what I copied from Intellij. Strange is if you copy something from the intellij a second time, the error does not appear.
Any JetBrains program causes this problem. Android Studio, Intellij IDEA are good examples.